# kvm, pci passthrough: unable to detach nvidia card for kernel 5.4 andabove

Tags: nvidia, kvm-virtualization

Normally when using pci passthrough the nvidia driver is replaced by the vfio driver. setting the correct option in /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf achieve that.  Staring with kernel 5.4 The vfio driver is not loaded instead of the native nvidia driver. I do not want blacklist the nvidia driver, since I have 2 nvidia cards. Only one is used for the passthrough. I had no issues with kernels 5.3.0-19 and below.

What is the correct way of assigning the vfio driver to one of the nvidia cards in the new kernels.

Comment: You haven't mentioned any OS/release details, and the only Ubuntu release using 5.4 is currently still in development and thus off-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I did not mention because I am testing the mainline kernel (5.4 and above) . I have ubuntu 19.10. My default kernel is (5.3.0-19).  Above 5.3.0-19 I have a different issue that is specific to my gtx 1660ti card. So I am stack with this kernel.  Also my question was a general question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you solved this, but I also had my VFIO configuration stop working after the update to Kubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.4. The solution was something that I had not had to do before,here is the link to the solution that I used. In case the link is broken in the future, I am including the information below so that people can find it.

https://github.com/rmayobre/PopOs-VFIO-Tutorial/wiki/VFIO-Steps

> Step 1 - Install the required software
>
> You will need QEMU, Virt-Manager, as well as some packages. Run this
>   line:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system bridge-utils virt-manager ovmf
> ```
>
> Step 2 - Add required kernel parameters
>
> ```
>  sudo kernelstub -a 'intel_iommu=on'
>     sudo kernelstub -a 'iommu=pt'
>     sudo kernelstub -a 'iommu=1'
>     sudo kernelstub -a "pci=noaer" Add this if you have problems with your VM starting when a USB Controller is attached.
> ```
>
> Step 3 - Look up PCI devices by ID
>
> NOTE: make sure you write down the IDs (you will need them later). GPU
>   and Audio output
>
> Run the command: lspci -vnn and search for the GPU you wish to
>   pass-through to guest OS. The Audio output of your GPU should be
>   underneath it. Your output should look something like this (of course
>   if you're using Radeon it would say otherwise):
>
> ```
> 09:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070 Ti] [10de:1b82] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA
> ```
>
> controller])
>       09:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f0] (rev a1)
>
> Remember the numbers in front of your device (e.g. 09:00.0 and
>   09:00.1). Step 4 - Attach VFIO drivers to PCI devices
>
> We need to bind the VFIO drivers to our GPU, as well as our GPU's
>   audio controller. To do this, we will create a script to help us
>   attach VFIO drivers to specified PCI devices. Create this file:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/bind_vfio.sh
> ```
>
> Then paste this script inside the newly created file:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> PREREQS=""
> DEVS="0000:09:00.0 0000:09:00.1"
> for DEV in $DEVS;
>   do echo "vfio-pci" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$DEV/driver_override
> done
>
> modprobe -i vfio-pci
> ```
>
> Replace 0000:09:00.0 and 0000:09:00.1 with your GPU numbers (NOTE: you
>   must append 0000: to the beginning of your numbers). Add your script
>   to the initial ram disk
>
> This can be done by making the script executable:
>
> ```
> sudo chmod 755 /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/bind_vfio.sh
> ```
>
> Now add the script:
>
> ```
> sudo chown root:root /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/bind_vfio.sh
> ```
>
> Finally, update the initial ram:
>
> ```
> sudo update-initramfs -u
> ```
>
> You can then verify the initial ramdisk does indeed have the script
>   ready by running this(replace /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-55-generic with
>   your file):
>
> ```
> sudo lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-55-generic |grep vfio
> ```
>
> Now we have to append vfio-pci to this file and save:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
> ```
>
> Run this again:
>
> ```
> sudo update-initramfs -u
> ```
>
> Reboot your system. When it comes online, run this:
>
> ```
> lspci -nnv
> ```
>
> Your GPU should have Kernel driver in us: vfio-pci (like this output):
>
> ```
> 09:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070 Ti] [10de:1b82] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA
> ```
>
> controller])
>         Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070 Ti] [1462:330f]
>         Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 70, NUMA node 0
>         Memory at b0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
>         Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
>         Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
>         I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
>         Expansion ROM at b1000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
>         Capabilities: 
>         Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
>         Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
>
> ```
> 09:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f0] (rev a1)
>   Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [1462:330f]
>   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 71, NUMA node 0
>   Memory at b1080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>   Capabilities: <access denied>
>   Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
>   Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
> ```
>
> Step 5 - Done
>
> If you have got this far, you are finished with setting up the VFIO
>   drivers. You can now move onto the section about configuring virtual
>   machines and Virt-Manager. Pages 5 VFIO and GPU Passthrough
>
> ```
> Home
> Hardware Configurations
> VFIO Attachment
> Virtual Machine Configurations
> Windows 10 Install
> ```
>
> Clone this wiki locally

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue as follows: all I had to do is reassign the pci BEFORE X11 starts. It was X11 not the nvidia driver that blocked the pci assignment. I have the following in my rc.local:

```
/usr/bin/virsh nodedev-detach pci_0000_17_00_0
echo "vfio-pci" > "/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:17:00.3/driver_override"
```

my biggest issue was with "nvidia-gpu" module which not used for graphics. It was used in pci bus 17:00.3. I had to blacklist this kernel module as well. This did not blacklist the graphics nvidia module.

Answer (score 0):

Pleas check it,
someone solved it with :

```
mkinitcipio -P linux-vfio and vfio kernel.
```

[Original solution](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/no-video-signal-from-windows-10-gpu-passthrough/139485)